# put request on iis returns a 401 error - Server error Access denied

Tags: iis, put

I'm trying to send a put request using Fiddler to an iis app. It fails with a 401 error but other verbs such as post work fine.
I've:

- tried the suggestion in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joseph_fultz/archive/2009/07/23/enabling-the-put-verb-with-handlers-and-iis-7-0.aspx
  by modifying applicationHost.config to add PUT to SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated
- tried modifying web.config as below:

```html
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs>
        <add verb="GET,PUT,POST,HEAD" allowed="true" />
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
    responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
    responseBufferLimit="0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Does anyone know how to enable put on iis 7.5?

Comment: What type of authentication is enabled for this application?

Comment: It's using networkservice. I also tried localsystem.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of answers around the WebDAV module that a little searching will find.

Another thing to try is switching `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to `<modules />`.
This worked for me on an IIS/node install.